# iOS Watch App Push Notifications Crash

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I'm experiencing a crash that happens when you click on a push notification from the pull down. When a push notification is received on my watch and you don't tend to it for 1+ mins, it will be in your notifications drop down.

Clicking on this PN causes the crash.

For short/long notifications, it doesn't crash when you view the PN.

In my Storyboard, I have a default notification controller with empty name which is for our Default notifications.'

I've also got notification controllers that handle the various categories of PNs.

Any ideas why a PN will cause this crash?

Our payload for our PNs has an alert key which is a String and not a Dictionary

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Test PN message!",
        "category": "some_notification",
    },
... 
}
```

Notice that our alert is not a dictionary and is a string.

Comment: Your alert string should be fine. Do you see a crash if you view the notification immediately? Are you sure the category you define in the payload is a category that is defined in your app? Without some code this is almost impossible to debug.

Comment: There are some PNs with categories that aren't defined in the notification controllers but those should use the default notification controller as per documentation.

Comment: Even the categories that are defined, they are fine, but crashes when viewed from the notification drop down bar. There are some PNs that crash immediately on receiving on the watch; I then removed the default notification controller in the storyboard and they don't crash anymore, but they still crash when clicking on it from the notifications bar.

Comment: I had an issue with notifications crashing because I used an image in my storyboard that was set to size proportionately. I ended up giving the image a static height and width and my crash went away.

Comment: Interesting! I'm going to check this out.

Comment: i am having the same issue on iOS 10 + watchOs 3